# C2065: 'D3DFORMAT': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, sdk, directx

When I tried to compile simple GTA San Andreas ASI (dll) project using SDK, I saw error 
`C2065 'D3DFORMAT': undeclared identifier.`

Line: `RwBool _rwD3D9CheckValidCameraTextureFormat(D3DFORMAT format); // 0x4CBE20`

Interesting thing is that, a few months ago, before reset to factory settings (Windows 10) all was ok.
I tried on Visual Studio 2015/2017/2019.

My code is so simple, because all is in SDK. (https://github.com/DK22Pac/plugin-sdk)

```
#include "plugin.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "CTimer.h"
#include "CStreaming.h"

using namespace plugin;

class PlayerWeapon {
public:
    PlayerWeapon() {
        static int keyPressTime = 0;
        Events::gameProcessEvent += [] {
            CPed *playa = FindPlayerPed();
            if (playa && KeyPressed(VK_TAB) && CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds - keyPressTime > 500) {
                keyPressTime = CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds;
                CStreaming::RequestModel(MODEL_M4, 2);
                CStreaming::LoadAllRequestedModels(false);
                playa->GiveWeapon(WEAPON_M4, 10, true);
                playa->SetCurrentWeapon(WEAPON_M4);
                CStreaming::SetModelIsDeletable(MODEL_M4);
            }
        };
    }
} playerWeapon;
```

Comment: That's a Direct3D 9 structure. Not sure if the Windows SDK comes with DirectX 9 SDK. So you might have to install DirectX SDK which includes support for DirectX 9.

Comment: Direct3D 9 headers are part of the Windows 10 SDK. D3DX9 is not. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-) and [this blog post](https://aka.ms/dxsdk).